Can template bases be a viable alternative to virtual bases?
Say I have an abstract base class:
class AbstractBase {
public:

   virtual void a() = 0;
   virtual void b() = 0;
   virtual void c() = 0;
};

One of the methods, a(), will be implemented by the most-derived type, but b() and c() have defaults that usually (but not always) apply.  The question is how best to allow authors of the most derived types to be able to use the default implementations of b() and/or c() without forcing them to.  The default behaviors of b() and c() are independent, so end users may want either or both.
The obvious answer would be to provide implementations for b() and c() in AbstractBase, but those implementations depend on data members that I don't want AbstractBase to have (types that don't use the defaults may not need the data members).
The main constraint is that objects of the derived type will be created and destroyed very frequently, so I want as little overhead for that as possible.  If not for that, I would probably just use strategy objects to implement the methods, but I don't want extra dynamic allocations to happen for each object.
The other issue is that many different derived classes will be written by many different users, so I want the job of the derived-class authors to be as simple as possible, particularly since they may not be experts the more esoteric parts of the language.
I can think of three alternatives, and I was hoping to get some feedback.  What appears to me to be the most workable solution isn't quite like any pattern or technique I've read about, so I'm concerned I may be missing something.

Virtual inheritance

class BImpl : public virtual AbstractBase
{
public:
   void b() { ... }
};

class CImpl : public virtual AbstractBase
{
public:
   void c() { ... }
};

class Derived1 : public BImpl, public CImpl
{
public:
   void a() { ... };
};

class Derived2 : public BImpl
{
public:
   void a() { ... };
   void c() { ... };
};

I'm sure this works, but I like to avoid this structure whenever possible. Even if there's no ambiguity now, it can creep in over the years as things change, construction of derived types is a mess if any of these classes take constructor arguments, and users of this library strongly dislike multiple inheritance and especially virtual inheritance.  I'm also not sure if there is any performance cost for creating objects that use virtual inheritance.

Policies

This is essentially the strategy pattern, but using templates to do strategy-selection at compile-time to avoid dynamic allocation.
template <class BPolicy, class CPolicy>
class Impl : public AbstractBase
{
public:

   // perhaps fancier constructors to support moves 
   Impl( BPolicy bpol, CPolicy cpol ) : b_policy{b_pol}, c_policy{c_pol} {}

   void b() { b_policy.b(); }
   void c() { c_policy.c(); }

private:
   BPolicy b_policy;
   CPolicy c_policy;
};

class Derived : public Impl<MyBPolicy, MyCPolicy>
{
public:
  
   // constructor not shown to initialize Impl

   void a() { ... }
};

I think this should work as well.  My main concern with it is that when users want to write their own implementation of b() or c(), they'll probably get into more template syntax than they'll want.

Template Bases

This idea is similar to some ideas I've ready about (such as mixins), but isn't exactly like any of them.  The idea is (like a mixin) to avoid multiple inhertiance by using template base classes.  Unlike mixins, though, it is using base classes to add implementations, not interfaces.
template <class Base>
class BImpl : public Base
{
public:
   void b() { ... };
};

template <class Base>
class CImpl : public Base
{
public:
   void c() { ... };
};

using BothDefaults = CImpl<BImpl<AbstractBase>>;

class Derived : public BothDefaults
{
public:
   void a() { ... };
};

Not shown is a bit of mess in the constructors of BImpl and CImpl (if any of these classes take constructor arguments, it involves variadic templates to forward constructor arguments to a base class whose type you don't know), but it's the same idea as a mixin.
My take on it is that this seems clean and easier for non-expert users to extend (although perhaps not as easy to understand) than the alternatives.  My only concern is that I haven't seen this mixin-like structure used for implementations, so I'm concerned that there might be a problem that I'm overlooking.
Is this a good way to solve this problem?  Would one of the other alternatives be better?

In general you either have dynamic polymorphism (abstract baseclasses) or static polymorphism (templates/type erasure), not a mix of both. Though implementation classes of abstract base classes may be templated. Then as a last option there is CRTP/Mixin (which I think is kind of what you are trying in your final example). In the end this question needs closing, because the answers will be opinon based (or too dependent on your use-case which we know nothing about)

Possibly: struct Base { void std::function<void()> a; void std::function<void()> b = defaultB; void std::function<void()> c = defaultC; };.

there is not one design that fits all. All 3 approaches you outlined have their place somewhere. Its your detailed(!) requirements that should drive the decision for one or the other. What you tell us here is rather vague, and unless you need something else go for the simple, what Jarod42 suggested seems to be totally fine.
